# Getting info about a Delayed::Job's instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I want to do something like this:

`Delayed::Job.first.model` => which should return the model, like the User instance or whatever, that was enqueued. How can I do that? Nothing in the docs, looked through all DJ methods to no avail...

Comment: what about `payload_object`?

Comment: look in documentation here http://rubydoc.info/gems/delayed_job/3.0.1/frames, don't look in a too recent version, they seem broken.

Comment: @juan Yes, `payload_object.object` works, feel free to add it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `payload_object` to get it. :)